# Is there a difference between "эго" and "это" or the are the same?

Tags: произношение, правописание, буквы

I have 2 questions about the same words:

**1**. Is there a difference between **эго** and **это** or the are the same? 
 (I've noticed that the uses of both is almost in the same context, and I suspect that they are synonyms.)

**2**. In addition, I'm not sure if the letter **г** in this case is pronounced the same as the letter **т**, and then эго and это are pronounced the same.

Comment: Please provide examples when you think это and эго mean the same (can be interchangeable).

Comment: As mentioned below, you probably confused eго and эго, because I can't understand why these totally different words can be the same.

Answer (score 8):

These are two completely different words.

`Эго` is a noun which means ego. In most cases, it means a (usually boosted) sense of self-importance, for example `у него непомерно раздутое эго`. In Russian, эго in such meaning has negative connotations. Sometimes эго means Freudian or philosophical concept of ego.

`Это` means it. (There are other, similar, meanings.)

Sometimes, `это` is mistyped as `эго`, as a typo. Often the source of the typo is a computer recognition error. Since г and т are visually similar, and both words do exist, a recognition software can easily confuse between the two words.  Example:

```
Но эго как раз тот случай, когда интуиция обманывает.
```

This is an obvious typo (should be `это`).

Answer (score 5):

My intuition is that perhaps you meant ***его*** (as a Single Genitive Case of ***он(о)***) instead of ***эго***, which is more likely to be 'used almost in the same context' as ***это***, or perhaps   ***него***.

The differences shall be as follows:

1. ***это*** (Gen. Sg. ***этого*** [étava]) = a) demonstrative pronoun (or b) neutrum descriptive pronoun).

a) ***Это миелофон.*** = This is a mind-reading device.

b) ***Это слово - из фантастического фильма.*** = This word [comes] from a sci-fi movie.

Cf: ***Этот миелофон не работает / выключен.*** = This mind-reading device is off.

2. ***его*** [(j)ivó] = Gen. Sg. of ***он*** (he => him) or ***это*** (it), used most often as a case of direct (*animate*, in case of ***он***) object, or as b) Partitive Genitive, or as c) Possessive Genitive, or :

a) ***Вижу его.*** = I see him / it.

b) ***Его там нет.*** = He is not there (lit. it's like 'There is no him there').

c) ***Это - его.*** = This belongs to him / This is his (lit. = ...of him).

3. ***него*** [nivó]  = Gen.Sg.2 , used most often with prepositions:

***Это - для / от него.*** = This is for / from him.

***Этого*** = Gen. Sg. of ***это*** or ***этот*** (both as demonstrative and descriptive pronoun):

***У меня этого нет. / Это у меня.*** = I don't have it/this/that.// I have it/this/that.

Other examples (try to deduce to which type of usage each form is related):

***Этот миелофон - у меня.*** = I have (got) this/that mind-reading device.

***У него этого миелофона нет.***  = He doesn't have this/that/such a mind-reading device.

***У него этого нет.*** = He doesn't have this/that/it. = ***У него его нет.*** = He doesn't have this/that/it / He is not at his place (chez lui).

***У меня его нет.*** = I don't have this/that/it. / He is not at my place (chez moi).

Therefore I suppose that perhaps you meant the interchangeability of **это** VS **его** in the sub-category of 2. a) and 2.b types (direct objects and existential sentences).

So, basically, the interchangeability between **это** and **его** occurs in a case of Masculine (Inanimate) nouns.

Comment: This isn't how you spell миелофон.

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov Right